# Excel Conditional Goal Seek

Tags: microsoft-excel

Is it is possible to have the Excel Function Goal Seek stop when a certain is value is met or exceeded? E.g. Set cell A1 to be >10 by changing cell B1.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Set cell `C1` (or some other unused cell) to `=A1>=10`. 
I’m using `>=` since your words say
“when a certain is value is *met or* exceeded”. 
Of course, if you want `A1` to be strictly greater than 10, then use `=A1>10`.

Then use Goal Seek to set `C1` to 1 (the numeric value of TRUE).

OR, set `C1` to be `=MIN(A1,10)` and seek to set `C1` to 10. 
If Excel finds a value for which `A1` is 17,
then `C1` will be `MIN(17,10)`, which is 10, and so Excel will stop searching.